# HTML map that I can add images over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help with a design for a web application I want to create.  Basically I want to start with a black background..let's say 1000px X 1000px.  Then on an event..lets say a click event, I want to be able to add a small image of a star on top of that background at the coordinates of my choice.  And keep doing that until I have a bunch of stars on the black background.

I don't know how to set up my html to be able to do this.  Once I have the overall design I can take it from there, I just don't know where to start.

Languages: HTML, Javascript, CSS

Starting Image:

[image: Starting Image:]

Image to Add:

[image: Image to Add:]

Ending Image:
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of this pursuit?

Comment: I want to create a donation site and every time someone donates it adds a star to the background.  The bigger the donation the brighter the star.  And eventually you can zoom in on stars and click them to see who donated.

Comment: You will need to learn a server side language to keep track of where all the stars are added otherwise you will end up with a blank canvas each time.

Comment: Thanks Billy, I do at least have some familiarity with Java so I should be better off there.

Comment: We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…

a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
**software tools commonly used by programmers;** and is
**a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**

How does this question not fit the bolded text?  I would love to hear your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mpprq3r3/

Heres a very simple example. Look at how its done and change it to fit your needs.

```
$(".canvas").on("click", function(e) {
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
    var relX = e.originalEvent.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var relY = e.originalEvent.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    console.log(relX)

    $(this).append("<div class='item' style='top:"+(relY-5)+"px;left:"+(relX-5)+"px'><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Crjc.png' /></div>");
});
```

Comment: I like that a lot, thank you